# How to send date to child components in next using getStatisticProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I read that I can use getStatisticProps only in pages area, but can I use a template from components?

I want to send date from pages/index.js

```
export default function Home({posts}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>NextJs is so cool</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="my new wonderful page"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      
      <CustomComponents data={posts}/>
  
      
      
    
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```

to CustomComponents.js and from there to blog section:

```
const CustomComponents = ({posts}) => {
  return (
    <div>
   ...
  
      <BlogComponent data={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomComponents;
```

but there is an error when I use this date in bloc section - posts.title.render[0] do not exist...

```
const BlogComponent = ({posts}) => {

{posts.title.rendered}

 );
};

export default BlogComponent;
```

where I make an mistake? or just it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You passing it as `data={posts}`

```js
export default function Home({posts}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>NextJs is so cool</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="my new wonderful page"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      // You pass posts to child component as name data
      <CustomComponents data={posts}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So in your **Child** component you should destruct it like this and so on:

```js
// Child.jsx
const CustomComponents = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      // rest of you code
      <BlogComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomComponents;
```

Still If you want to pass props to nested component tree ([prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)) you use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to make it easier.